# Determining, without recourse to complex analysis, which functions $f: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ converge to their Taylor series

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

One conceptual stumbling block for me—and for many others, I'm sure— in introductory calculus was that it was never explained how we could be sure that a function $f: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ actually converged to its power series—it seemed implausible that a function's derivatives at one point could determine it completely, even for a short interval. Of course, this isn't true; there are well-known examples of functions with distinct values everywhere but one point $x \in \mathbf{R}$ but with identical convergent Taylor series about $x$—for example, $$ \begin{align*} f(x) &= 0 \\ g(x) &= \begin{cases} e^{-1/x^2} & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0, \end{cases} \end{align*}$$
both of which have zero derivatives of all orders at $x=0$. We can explain why $g$ never equals its Taylor series with complex analysis: the complex function $g: \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C}$ given by $g(z) = e^{-1/z^2}$ has a singularity at the origin, going to $0$ if approached along the real axis but to $+\infty$ if approached along the imaginary axis, and thus doesn't have complex derivatives at the origin at all. But this requires students to understand the notions of holomorphic and analytic functions, and some basic results of complex analysis such as the Cauchy integral formula. **Without using complex analysis, can we prove whether any function of one real variable, besides polynomial functions, converges to its Taylor series?** At the very least, is it possible to prove this of the more commonly seen functions in basic calculus—ratios of polynomials, sines, cosines, logarithms, and exponents?

Comment: I recall from teaching out of Stewart's Calculus text that one can check that the remainder of the Taylor series converge to 0 by the standard error estimates and sandwich theorem. This is easiest with exp, sin and cos, since it's fairly easy to compute and bound their derivatives. You can use the geometric series for at least some rational functions. Also, you can integrate analytic functions term by term (requires some justification) to get log.

Comment: Personally, I think that holomorphic functions are *the right way* to understand when does the function converge to its Taylor series, and that the restriction to the real analisys is artificial here. Actually, there are some tricks you can use to prove directly that the Taylor series of logarithm converges to logarithm, for example, but they are tedious and hide the real nature of the subject.

Comment: @minimalrho Yes, but I thought error formulas and such let you test _whether the Taylor series has a limit_, but not _whether the limit of the series equals the function that the series was derived from_. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ConnorHarris Check for example Theorem 5.15 of baby Rudin (or google Taylor's theorem). It states that the function is equal to the Taylor polynomial plus an error term. If you show the error goes to zero, then the function converges to the Taylor series.

Comment: Just take a look at any calculus text. It's called Taylor's theorem, and it's proof involves no complex analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about the collection of all *real analytic* functions. To check that the Taylor series (centered at a particular point) converges to the correct function on the interval of convergence requires considering the remainder term $R_n$ for the $n$th degree Taylor polynomial and showing that this converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ for all $x$ in the interval. [It's also not too hard to show by analyzing these remainder estimates that functions "built" out of real analytic functions — by differentiating, integrating, adding, multiplying, dividing, etc. — are again real analytic on the appropriate domain.]

For the function $g$ you brought up, no complex analysis whatsoever is needed. You just need to argue (by an induction argument, knowing that exponentials go to $\infty$ faster than any polynomial at infinity) that all the derivatives of $g$ at $0$ are in fact $0$. So in this case $R_n(x)=g(x)$ for all $n$, and the criterion fails.

Answer (score 1):

Trigonometric, hyperbolic and exponential functions are analytic since they're *defined* as sums of power series. The same is true for rational functions, since the quotient of two analytic functions is analytic on any open set of its domain.

Comment: May I know why this down vote?

Comment: upvoted .......